# How to change color of frames in xcode (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, frame

so I used this code:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    frame.origin.y += 4;
    frame.size.height -= 2 * 4;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

I saw from one of the posts in this site to put spaces between my custom cells. I was wondering if there's a way to change its colour? It's currently white. Or if there's a way to make it transparent?

[image: This is how it looks like. I just want to change the color of the white frame between the cells]

Comment: Give some detailed info?

Comment: A frame (CGRect) is literally just a definition of a space. It has no colour. It is not a thing. A view uses a frame to define it's position and size. You can change the background colour of a view. By the way, find a more up-to-date tutorial. What you are doing is very outdated.

Comment: For what you are setting this frame? Give some piece of code what you've done.

Comment: @pikapikaprogrammer sorry, that was a bit harsh. You should be able to set `self.backgroundColor` in the code that you have put and it will change the background color of whatever it is you are changing the frame of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried this and it worked:

```
UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 10)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:206/255.0 green:191/255.0 blue:170/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to color space between cells, try:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // This should give you transparent color
```